# How to replace NaN and Inf using 1 of the 2 matrices value?

Tags: r, matrix, replace, nan

I have 2 large matrices with 100 columns and 10,000 rows. I am trying to divide `a` by `b` and calculate log2, and then abs().

```
a<-c(2,0,2,3,0,6)
b<-c(0,1,4,6,0,6)
a/b
Inf 0.0 0.5 0.5 NaN 1.0
```

I would like to use "2" instead of "Inf" and use "0" instead of NaN.

Comment: It sounds like you want a function that will replace all instances of `Inf` with 2 and that will replace all instances of `NaN` with 0.  Is that correct?  You want a function that will do this to every cell `c` of the matrix: If `c=Inf`` then return 2, else if `c=NaN` then return 0, else return `c`, right?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. For NaN, I want to replace all NaN in matrix with "0", but replace Inf using the non-zero value in either of the 2 matrices at the corresponding position. Here in matrix "a", the first value is "2", in matrix "b", the first value is "0", I got Inf when a/b. So I want use the value in "a" which is "2" to replace Inf. Explain clearly?

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
res <- a/b;
res[is.infinite(res)] <- a[is.infinite(res)];
res[is.nan(res)] <- 0;
```

Although, note, the documentation to `is.nan` says:

```
Computations involving ‘NaN’ will return ‘NaN’ or perhaps ‘NA’:
which of those two is not guaranteed and may depend on the R
platform (since compilers may re-order computations).
```

I get `NaN` though.

Comment: This is a good answer (I upvoted) for what I thought the original question was, too.  However, OP Zeng's comment at about the same time shows that a more complex operation is needed--which can be built partly out of the tools that you have provided.

Comment: I just changed the code to do what the added comment above made clear was wanted, instead of always replacing `Inf` with 2, it should return  the value of a. I think this is what you're after.

Comment: thanks a lot! that is what exactly what I want. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you just don't want to divide by 0 and when `b==0` just return the corresponding value of `a`. If that's the case, no need to work on `Inf` and `NaN`: just replace the 0s in `b` with ones.

```
b[b==0]<-1
a/b
#[1] 2.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0
```

Comment: Or if the OP don't want to change the original object `a/replace(b, !b, 1)`